# Format Time in Xaml

Tags: wpf

I need to format a field in the datagrid in xaml to look like "10 march 2010 19:50"
at the moment i have

```
   Binding="{Binding Path=MyDate, StringFormat=\{0:d MMM yyyy\}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

How Can I change so that also the time gets displayed?
thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Binding="{Binding Path=MyDate, StringFormat={0:d MMM yyyy hh:mm}, Mode=OneWay}"

Comment: Thanks for your reply.It did not work.Is it because of "0:d" should it be something else to represent the time as well.I forgot